# SWIG typemap to return an output param char*/size_t

Tags: python, swig

I have an C API that uses output params for strings. *(The real signature has been changed to protect the innocent. This is a simplistic example.)*

```
void func( char* buf, size_t buflen, char* buf2, size_t buf2len );
```

`buf` and `buflen` are effectively output parameters, where `buflen` and `buf2len` are the (already) allocated size of those buffers.

In the calling code, I don't want to have to pass in any parameters. Rather, I want the strings to be returned.

```
result1,result2 = func()
```

I would prefer not to pass the buffer/size to the wrapper function, but rather have it allocated by the wrapper, turned into a Python string, and deallocated before returning the Python string.

Most of the [cstring.i](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/ocaml/cstring.i) typemaps I see related to this require me to give the wrapper function a string. The allocate typemaps all want a `char**`.

I'm looking for behavior similar to using `OUTPUT` as an outparam name, but the buffer/size pair are the (single) outparam.

I don't have power to alter the API. I just want to make it easy to use.

Is there already a typemap for this, or can you help me construct one?

### Trial 1 (Python Only)

I got this to function (no test of performance or memory usage).

```
%typemap(in,numinputs=0)(char* mutable_buffer, size_t mutable_buffer_size) {
    $1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*4096);
    $1[0] = 0x0;
    $2 = 4096;
}
%typemap(argout)(char* mutable_buffer, size_t mutable_buffer_size) {
#ifdef SWIGPYTHON
    PyObject *o;
    $1[4095] = 0x0; // null-terminate it, just in case
    o = PyUnicode_FromString($1);
    resultobj = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput(resultobj,o);
#endif
}
%typemap(freearg)(char* mutable_buffer, size_t mutable_buffer_size) {
    free($1);
}
```

I would prefer to solve this problem without resorting to lang-specific fixes.

Comment: If you want an output, it has to be `char**` otherwise you cannot modify the pointer.

Comment: @JensMunk If you pass in a previously allocated `char*` and a `size_t` indicated how big it is, the function can write data to it without allocating it.

Comment: You are right, but this is then also an input - a quite annoying way of handling outputs. If outputs are handled this way, it would make sense to provide a function which returns an integer, which is the size the user needs to allocate before calling func

Comment: In this case, as the wrapper maintainer, I can know some reasonable bounds to place on the strings. From the client's point of view (especially in a scripting language), they don't want to fool with string sizes, etc. If I know that everything will always fit into 4096 bytes, then the client doesn't need to tell me how big it might be, and I can just return a string.

Comment: In this case, there are many options. You can include `%include "carrays.i"` and `%array_class(char, charArray)`.. Allocate a char array using `carr = lib.charArray(4096)` and simple pass this as an argument.

Comment: @JensMunk, Thanks for the tip. I updated my question with some code that I got to function, though I'm not partial to that solution. I'd much prefer to use SWIG things that rely on SWIG's code generation, rather than my own. Will using `carrays.i` allow me to solve the problem (including the return value) in a language-neutral way?

Comment: The `typemap` that you have written will work for Python. If you change your interface to `func(char** ppChar, int* pSize)` you can create the wrapper using the contents of `cstring.i` and it will work for all languages. Similarly, the solution using `carrays.i` will work for all languages

Comment: I can't change the API. Is there no way to solve this problem for all languages?

Comment: If you want to stick with SWIG's predefined typemaps, you can use `carrays.i` as I suggested, but then you need to allocate a char array in the target language. If you want a typemap, which allocates, you need to write your own

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192382/discussion-between-jens-munk-and-mojo).

Answer (score 1):

Since you've specifically asked for solutions which don't need anything language specific to support I'd suggest using `%inline` to provide an alternative form of `func` which has the syntax you prefer. Something like this should do it:

```
%module test

%rename(func) func_adjusted; 
%newobject func_adjusted();

%inline %{
  struct func1_out {
    // can make tuple syntax work here if you would rather, but likely having names is clearer anyway
    char buf1[4096];
    size_t buf1len;
    char buf2[4096];
    size_t buf2len;
  };

  // with the rename we pretend this is the C function, but really it is specific to our wrapper module.
  struct func1_out *func_adjusted() {
    struct func1_out *ret = malloc(sizeof *ret);
    // could also dynamically allocate buf1 and buf2 instead of fixed max size.
    func(buf1, &buf1len, buf2, &buf2len);
    return ret;
  }
%}

%ignore func;
%include "blahblah.h"
```

You'll likely want to do a little more work with the `char buf1` and `buf2` arrays inside that struct, to make it more natural to the Python user, but that can be done with carrays.i or `%extend` on the struct to keep it all in C/SWIG and not Python specific still.

---

You can also do something that isn't specific to the function you're wrapping, using multi argument typemaps. To avoid getting Python specific you can use `%append_output` to return multiple items from one function. This doesn't work for statically typed languages like Java or C# though, but it should work for most/all dynamically typed ones.

To further avoid needing extra, language specific code we can use carrays.i, which generates some extra functions for each type we define. In particular we use `ByteArray_cast`, `new_ByteArray` and `delete_ByteArray` to handle a fairly large number of cases we might encounter. This should work for both C and C++ cases.

```
%module test

%include <carrays.i>
%array_class(char, ByteArray);

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) (char* mutable_buffer, size_t mutable_buffer_size) (ByteArray *tmp=NULL) {
    // N.B. using new_ByteArray() here makes this work well with both C and C++ code
    tmp = new_ByteArray(4096);
    $1 = ByteArray_cast(tmp);
    $1[0] = 0x0;
    $2 = 4096;
}

%typemap(freearg) (char* mutable_buffer, size_t mutable_buffer_size) {
    // conditional is needed here as in some cases delete_ByteArray would dereference a null pointer
    if (tmp$argnum) delete_ByteArray(tmp$argnum);
}

%typemap(argout) (char* mutable_buffer, size_t mutable_buffer_size) {
   // Take ownership from in typemap
   %append_output(SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(tmp$argnum), $descriptor(ByteArray*), SWIG_POINTER_NEW));
   tmp$argnum = NULL;
}

%apply (char *mutable_buffer, size_t mutable_buffer_size) { (char *buf, size_t buflen), (char *buf2, size_t buf2len) };

%inline %{
void func(char* buf, size_t buflen, char* buf2, size_t buf2len) {
  strncpy(buf, "this is buffer1", buflen);
  strncpy(buf2, "this is buffer2", buf2len);
}
%}
```

This works as expected with Python 3.7 in my testing. Note that you'll need to run swig with the `-builtin` argument to get the exact behaviour you're looking for here, or require extra user code for a workaround:

```
a,b = test.func()
# needed for the non builtin case, I can't see a way to avoid that without Python specific code
aa=test.ByteArray_frompointer(a)
# for the -builtin case it just works though
```

---

There aren't a whole lot of choices for neat interfaces here because your requirements are quite restrictive:

1. without resorting to lang-specific fixes.
2. I don't have power to alter the API. I just want to make it easy to use.

With those two taken into consideration not much is left open to use.

Personally though I tend to prefer to write some Python specific C if it makes the interface that Python users see more natural, even if it means the same interface can't be 100% duplicated in another language. There are much neater solutions here for a little extra language specific work which usually pays off.

I'd argue that the power of SWIG isn't 'write once, import anywhere', but helping you abstract and modularise the language specific parts of an intuitive interface.

Comment: The down side of this is that I have to write a separate function for each API function I want to handle. I'm after a generic solution that works for all the similar (in terms of outparams) API functions. The typemaps seem to do this, based on the arg type and name, but there aren't any premade ones that do what I want.

Comment: The general advice I'd give is that you can pick only 2 out of these 3 things: Intuitive interface, language portability, minimal duplicitous boilerplate code. That said I'll have a look and see if there's anything else that might be workable. In this instance the aim of avoiding language specific fixes is extremely hard because not all languages can dynamically return tuple objects.

Comment: @mojo I added another example that more closely resembles your typemaps. I still don't much like it though compared to doing Python specific things and it can never work for dynamically typed languages without extra support, but it's probably the best you can get for what you're asking for.

Comment: I'd give you a +2 if I could. This answer was very helpful (for my understanding, too).